# Fast Implementation of TF-IDF

Tags: r, algorithm

I am trying to calculate Term Frequency Inverse Document Frequency to get normalized weights using below function. When the number of rows are in hundred's, the results are pretty quick, but, when the number of rows are in thousands (Just 20 thousand), It takes almost 3 to 4 minutes, to get the result. Can some one point me in right direction to  decrease the computational time?

```
tfidf=function(mat){
  mat = mat[,names]
  tf = mat/rowSums(mat)
  id=function(col){sum(!col==0)}
  idf = log10(nrow(mat)/apply(mat, 2, id))
  tfidf = mat
  for(word in names(idf)){tfidf[,word] <- tf[,word] * idf[word]}
  return(tfidf)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [`text2vec::`](http://text2vec.org/)'s `TfIdf()` class -- it is super fast when used in coordination with a matrix created by `text2vec::create_dtm()`. The interface is similar to `sklearn` if you've ever used that.

Check out [this part](http://text2vec.org/vectorization.html#tf-idf) of the vectorization vignette for an example of tfidf weighting in action.

(more generally, I've found most of `text2vec::`'s core functionality to be shockingly fast, so if you're using R for NLP this is a good option :p)